# Fastest way to save Preferences in an Android APP (Java)?

Tags: java, android

How would we go about saving preferences like some data (that doesnt need to be secure) on the device that also requires the least coding.

All I want to do is save for instance some text fields input so the user doesnt have to repeat himself next time he uses the APP.

The user should be able to then delete/update the previous input.
I don't want to use a database.

For instance, APP Has 2 Text Fields.

**Name and Last Name.** 
Where do I save this data (input) so that the user doesnt have to type it every time he opens the app.

Comment: You might want to read the documentation about that. https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences

Comment: I'll read the documentation but will still wait if any other answers are available as this is not an unique answer rather there could be many good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is pretty short...

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.saved_high_score_key), newHighScore);
editor.commit();
```

This is four lines, instead of putInt you could use putString, to put firstname and lastname into the required fields.

Comment: Great I will most likely do this, thank you!

Comment: No problem, if the solution works accept the answer :)